# Set position of spinner from variable

Tags: android, spinner

I have an activity that recieves two variables called l_source and l_destination and I want to set the default values of two spinners equal to those variables. To do so, I have made a search and I understand that I need to get the position of the value of the variable (will give a number) and then set the new position of the spinner. The problem is that I am trying to use `getAdapterPosition` and I am sent `Cannot resolve method getAdapterPosition(l_source)`.

**EDIT**

I finally managed to do it, but it is only working in one spinner. Have you got any idea of why? Here is my code:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.lista_origen);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(Main2Activity.this,
R.array.l_source, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner.setSelection(adapter.getPosition(l_source));

Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.lista_destino);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(Main2Activity.this,
R.array.l_source, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
spinner2.setSelection(adapter2.getPosition(l_target));
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

> get position of selected item is spinner by `int spinnerPosition = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();`

Comment: Are you sure that "getSelectedItemPosition" is going to give me the position of the item which is equal to a variable value?

Comment: "getSelectedItemPosition"  will give the position of selected item in spinner to set it to particular variable you will have to use setSelection();.... but do check it with array size to avoid array out of bound exception

Comment: This not what he want

Comment: what exactly you want... where do u get that variable ?